# The Traveling Salesman as Socialite

Tags: google-maps, gis, traveling-salesman

I have a Traveling Salesman problem with some additional constraint. (Note: this is not a homework problem, I've phrased it like one to abstract the problem.)

Given a list of events for a particular day with specific start times and end times, what is the optimal route to maximize the number of events attend? Assume the salesman/socialite must stay until the end of each event. While normal people might eye-ball the list and solve this the Socialite receives invites for up to 20 events each night.

How can one solve for something like this? So far I have investigated the directions API from Google Maps and ArcGIS route planner but the problem exceeds their capabilities.

Comment: Can someone fill me in on why this is getting down-voted? I don't mind re-tagging if it's in the wrong place.

Comment: It's not a matter of place I think, it's a matter of you asking for something off topic. Look here :http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic (point 4 of the off topic reasons. Asking for a tool or library is off-topic)

Comment: Fine. I've rephrased it. But for the record, I think that's a silly restriction as I've found countless great specific tool recommendations on StackOverflow. Sometimes they're even from the authors of the tools themselves. I think the intent of that rule is to avoid "What MVC framework should I use?" questions. This question is a lot less likely to start a holy war.

Comment: You're not wrong. Your question is way more precise than "what MVC framework".... you just asked why the downvote and I gave you a possible reason. And it's hard to look at questions and compare them to yours. Rules change. Most of these tool recommendation questions are old (or at least the ones I saw). Maybe stack was different back then...

Answer (score 1):

I don't see how this is related to GIS. But it can be modelled as a linear integer programming problem and solved if the only objective is to maximise the number of events attended (and not minimise the distance travelled).

objective function: max z = x(1) + x(2) + .... + x(N)

constraints:

for all x(i): x(i) = 0 or 1

for all x(i), x(j) where i != j: M.x(i).E(i) + T(i,j) <= M.x(j).S(i)

x(i) equals 1 if the ith event is attended, 0 otherwise. S(i) and E(i) represent the start and end times of the events, in terms of hours into the day. For example, if the 5th event on the list starts at 10am and ends at 11.30am, then S(5) is 10 and E(5) is 11.5. T(i, j) is the travel time between the locations that host event i and event j. M is a large arbitrary constant for scaling.

The objective function maximises the number of events attended. The first constraint specifies that each event is either attended or not attended. The second constraint ensures that if two events are attended, then the socialite has enough time to travel, between the ending time of the first attended event and the starting time of the second attended event.